# What kind of redraw does Chrome's Dev. tools cause?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, developer-tools

I'm experiencing a bug with Angular JS that has an odd work-around: Simply toggling the visibility of Chrome's Dev. Tools is the workaround for "fixing" what appears on the screen. This led me to investigate various methods for "redrawing" the document (window?).

What is Chrome's Dev. Tools doing that other techniques such as resizing the window *not* doing? Running
`$(window).trigger('resize');` did not fix the issue.

**UPDATE:** Also manually resizing the Chrome window fixes the issue.